# Working on a Web page effect of background image display/change on mouse pointer over the titles

Tags: jquery

I am working on a webpage and I would like to ask if it is possible to, on a list of art titles, have them open/change the plain background with the correct image just by moving the mouse pointer over the title.

I am also wondering if this approach to image display could benefit in anyway the illegal copy of pictures.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you've already tried.

Comment: Sure it is possible but this won't avoid any advanced user to copy these images

Comment: anything you send to browser can be copied

Comment: Two things I am trying to accomplish to make this page functional:                1) be able to ad plain black social icons on the upper right side of the page.                                                                                                               2) be able to have an different image displayed when moving the mouse pointer over each title.                                                                             The code is simple:

Comment: .                                                                                                                    The code is simple, but cluttered because was originally designed using word, I can send the file to any of you who were kind to answer